# Font already defined with incompatible format in Android Gradle build

Tags: android, gradle

I'm receiving the following 2 errors when trying to build my Android project with Gradle:

Error:(598) Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format.

Error:(2209, 39) String types not allowed (at 'android:typeface' with value 'roboto_medium').

I've looked online elsewhere but can't find the answer to these issues, any clarification or help is much appreciated.

Update:

Here is the stacktrace:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Attribute \"font\" already defined with incompatible format.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/johnbyrne/Documents/myapp-android/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/development/debug/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":597}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Original attribute defined here.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/johnbyrne/Documents/myapp-android/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/development/debug/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":417}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"String types not allowed (at \u0027android:typeface\u0027 with value \u0027roboto_medium\u0027).","sources":[{"file":"/Users/johnbyrne/Documents/myapp-android/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/development/debug/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":2208,"startColumn":38,"startOffset":158093,"endColumn":51,"endOffset":158106}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
Failed to generate resource table for split ''
/Users/johnbyrne/Documents/myapp-android/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/development/debug/values/values.xml:598: error: Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format.
/Users/johnbyrne/Documents/myapp-android/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/development/debug/values/values.xml:418: Original attribute defined here.
/Users/johnbyrne/Documents/myapp-android/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/development/debug/values/values.xml:2209: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'android:typeface' with value 'roboto_medium').
```

My styles.xml looks like this:

```
<resources>

    <style name="ButtonLight">
        <item name="android:typeface">roboto_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_button</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black_87</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">-2sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Custom fonts in your app then please check once Font or Typeface implemented correctly.

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular 
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light 
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed 
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"     // roboto black 
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2) 
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"    // roboto medium (android 5.0)




     <style name="ButtonLight">
           <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_button</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/black_87</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
            <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">-2sp</item>
            <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        </style>
```

Try this.

Comment: I've changed all the markup in styles.xml to: ```<item name="android:typeface">roboto_medium</item>``` instead of ```<item name="font">roboto_medium</item>``` but still get the above errors. I've also tried copying 'Roboto-Medium.ttf' into a new folder in res called 'font', but did not make any difference. I tried renaming it to 'roboto_medium.ttf', this still didn't resolve the issues.

Comment: Can you share styles.xml

Comment: Hi @Dipendra, I have updated my question with styles.xml. If possible can you update your response?

Comment: Hi Dipendra, I've changed all occurences of ```<item name="android:typeface">roboto_medium</item>``` to ```<item name="android:typeface"> sans-serif-medium </item>``` in build/intermediates/res/merged/development/debug they still show as ```<item name="android:typeface">roboto_medium</item>```. Should I try and clear the cache.